# Windows update fails and changes are reverted infinite

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-update

I have a fairly new Windows 7 installation. After boot it downloads and installs about 200 updates (which takes 1-2 hours). But after shutdown Windows try to finish configuration which fails and update is reverted. (which takes again 1-2 hours). Of course after reboot Windows starts again downloading/ installing and reverting updates.

Is there a way to force Windows to keep/resp. accept the update? Or at least find out which one out of these 200 updates fails?
I already disabled the virus scanner but it did not help.

Comment: `Or at least find out which one out of these 200 updates fails?` - You will have to install the updates in blocks in order to determine that.  The specific update that fails is of course in the logs, but easier for us, if you reduce the number of possible updates for us to identify.

Comment: only install 30-50 update in one step, reboot and install the next bunch of updates. If this still fails, copy the folder C:\windows\logs\cbs to your desktop, zip the folder and share the zip (onedrive or dropbox share link)

Answer (score 0):

I installed everything by chuncks of 20-30 updates and all are in now. At the end all updates were sucessfull.

Comment: ok, nice to hear that this worked